# How can you embed youtube videos that don't start the external player on Iphone?

Tags: iphone, youtube, youtube-api, embed

I'm trying to implement an embedded Youtube video in my application.
The only way I've managed to do this is with frameworks like [LBYouTubeView](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView) or [HCYotubeParser](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hcyoutubeparser). From what I've read they are against the Youtube TOS because they basically strip the video link from the http getting something like [this](http://r2---sn-gqn-ungl.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?source=youtube&ratebypass=yes&key=yt1&newshard=yes&mt=1365196042&expire=1365221166&dnc=1&el=watch&mv=m&itag=18&ms=au&upn=Z_v-Jvenvcs&cp=U0hVSlJNT19LUENONV9KR1NCOlFMSEJMQnZOT0JL&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ip=79.117.173.42&app=youtube_mobile&fexp=926501%2C929206%2C916612%2C902534%2C932000%2C906383%2C902000%2C901208%2C919512%2C929903%2C925714%2C931202%2C900821%2C900823%2C931203%2C931401%2C906090%2C909419%2C908529%2C930807%2C919373%2C930803%2C906836%2C920201%2C929602%2C930101%2C926403%2C900824%2C910223&id=e6f6a9f910a4d660&sver=3&yms=OOIZKDxQRZI&ipbits=8&signature=4CD8D523A3D8A3ECED84B02AC8A6C68B8C4FB9C9.2797544C51DACBC0E96C2CE0624B04BB9E0038FA).

This indeed can be played inside a MPMoviePlayerController without any problems (and without leaving the application).

From what I've search there are two applications that managed to do this [Vodio](http://www.vod.io/) and [Frequency](http://www.frequency.com/) so I'm wondering if there is a special sdk for developers or an affiliate program I might have missed.

From what I also read Youtube Engineers respond to this questions if they are tagged with youtube-api so I hope you could clear this up.

I've read about the UIWebView implementations but that scenario actually opens the an external video player which I have no control over.

Comment: So you want to embed the actual video into a media player, rather than (say) an iFrame or other web-based implementation?

Comment: Yes because the iFrame/Html code when tapped opens up an external player.

Comment: Hmm. The only way I could think of would be to use a UIWebView with a chromeless player, which you could retain control over via JavaScript, perhaps... https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started

Comment: Do you mean you want it to function like the official YouTube app which can show a video in embedded form on part of the screen and then user can optionally click to show it full screen? What do you mean by "external player"?

Comment: Yes like the one in the Youtube app or Vodio or Frequency. If the videos are not embedded like in those app they actually open up another player that you can't control because the application is in multitask at that point.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this afterwards?  I'm looking for the same thing and was going to use LBYouTubeView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked around for a while and this is what I came up with:
It involves adding a youtube.html file to your project with the following code:

```
<html>
<head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head>
<body>
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()
    {
    player = new YT.Player('player',
    {
      width: '640',
      height: '360',
      videoId: '%@',
      playerVars: {'autoplay' : 1, 'controls' : 0 , 'vq' : 'hd720', 'playsinline' : 1, 'showinfo' : 0, 'rel' : 0, 'enablejsapi' : 1, 'modestbranding' : 1},
      events:
        {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event)
    {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
    //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
    //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event)
    {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) 
        {
            window.location = "callback:anything"; 
        };
    }
    function stopVideo() 
    {
        player.stopVideo();
        window.location = "callback:anything";
    }
    function getTime()
    {
        return player.getCurrentTime();
    }
    function getDuration()
    {
        return player.getDuration();
    }
    function pause()
    {
        player.pauseVideo();
    }
    function play()
    {
        player.playVideo();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also you have to create a UiWebView subclass that is also a delegate for UIWebViewDelegate

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self == nil) return nil;

    self.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
    self.delegate = self;
    self.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = TRUE;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
    return self;
}

- (void)loadVideo:(NSString *)videoId
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YouTube" ofType:@"html"];
    //    if (filePath == nil)

    NSError *error;
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    // TODO: error check

    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:string, videoId];

    NSData *htmlData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //    if (htmlData == nil)

    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *targetPath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"youtube2.html"];
    [htmlData writeToFile:targetPath atomically:YES];

    [self loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:targetPath]]];
    File = 0;
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"callback"])
    {
        Playing = FALSE;

        NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *targetPath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"youtube2.html"];
        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:targetPath error:&error];       
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Basically it creates a UIWebView and loads the code in the youtube.html file. Because the youtube.html is static and I need to load a certain id I create a copy on the fly in the documents folder youtube2.html in which I add the string id.

The whole thing is that [self loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:targetPath]]]; works but loading a NSUrlRequest from a string doesn't.

The Javascript functions you see in the html file are for controlling the video. If you need access to time or full duration you can get them like this:

```
float VideoDuration = [[YT_WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getDuration()"] floatValue];
float VideoTime = [[YT_WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getTime()"] floatValue];
```